# Ошибка при записи в базу:SQL error or missing database (no such column:...)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

[image: Схема]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Столбцы есть, записей в БД нет.
[image: Скрин существующих столбцов в таблицах]

Ошибка при компиляции:

```
 org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: m.UsersId)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:941)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:953)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:918)
......
......

org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: c.ContractId)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:941)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:953)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:918)
```

......
......

Код:

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class contactQuery {
    public boolean insertContact(Contact cont)
    {

        boolean ContactIsCreated = true;
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:mase.db", "root", "root")){
           try(PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Users ( First_Name, Last_Name) VALUES (?, ?)"))
           {

               ps.setString(1, cont.getFirst_name());
               ps.setString(2, cont.getLast_name());
               ps.executeUpdate();

               if(ps.executeUpdate()!=0){
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Contact Added1");
                   ContactIsCreated = true;
               }
               else{
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"something wrong");
                   ContactIsCreated = false;
               }

           }
           catch(SQLException ex)
           {
               Logger.getLogger(contactQuery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
           }

            try(PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PhoneNumbers (NumberPrefix,Number) VALUES (?,?)")) {

                ps.setString(1, cont.getNumberPrefix());
                ps.setString(2, cont.getNumber());
                ps.executeUpdate();

                if (ps.executeUpdate() != 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Contact Added2");
                    ContactIsCreated = true;
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "something wrong");
                    ContactIsCreated = false;
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(contactQuery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
            }
            try(PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SRates (Rates) VALUES (?)"))
            {

                ps.setString(1, cont.getRates());
                ps.executeUpdate();


                if (ps.executeUpdate() != 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Contact Added3");
                    ContactIsCreated = true;
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "something wrong");
                    ContactIsCreated = false;
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(contactQuery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);

            }


            try(PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Pay ( Amount, PaymentDate, PaymentPlace ) VALUES (?,?,?) ")){
                ps.setString(1, cont.getAmount());
                ps.setString(2, cont.getPaymentDate());
                ps.setString(3, cont.getPaymentPlace());
                ps.executeUpdate();
                if (ps.executeUpdate() != 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Contact Added5");
                    ContactIsCreated = true;
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "something wrong");
                    ContactIsCreated = false;
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(contactQuery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
            }


            try(PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Cont ( StartDate,Balance,IsActive ) VALUES (?,?,?) ")){
                ps.setString(1, cont.getStartDate());
                ps.setString(2, cont.getBalance());
                ps.setString(3, cont.getIsActive());
                ps.executeUpdate();
                if (ps.executeUpdate() != 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Contact Added6");
                    ContactIsCreated = true;
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "something wrong");
                    ContactIsCreated = false;
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(contactQuery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
            }



            try(Statement statement = connection.createStatement()){
                String sql = "INSERT INTO Contracts (Id, UsersId, PhoneNumbersId, RatesId, StartDate, Balance, IsActive ) SELECT y.Id, m.UsersId, p.PhoneNumbersId,r.RatesId, StartDate, Balance, IsActive  FROM Cont y    LEFT JOIN Users m ON  m.Id=y.Id  LEFT JOIN PhoneNumbers p ON p.Id=y.Id  LEFT JOIN SRates r ON r.Id=y.Id";

                Boolean isRetrieved = statement.execute(sql);

                System.out.println("Is data retrieved: " + isRetrieved);

                try {
                    statement.close();
                    connection.close();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (statement != null)
                    {
                        statement.close();
                    }
                    if (connection != null)
                    {
                        connection.close();
                    }
                }

            }
            catch(SQLException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(contactQuery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
            }








            try(Statement statement = connection.createStatement()){
                String sql = " INSERT INTO Payments (Id, ContractId, Amount, PaymentDate, PaymentPlace) SELECT x.Id, c.ContractId , Amount, PaymentDate, PaymentPlace FROM Pay x INNER JOIN  Contracts c ON c.Id=x.Id";

                Boolean isRetrieved = statement.execute(sql);

                System.out.println("Is data retrieved: " + isRetrieved);

                try {
                    statement.close();
                    connection.close();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (statement != null)
                    {
                        statement.close();
                    }
                    if (connection != null)
                    {
                        connection.close();
                    }
                }

            }
            catch(SQLException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(contactQuery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
            }








        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(contactQuery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        }

        return ContactIsCreated;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В таблице `Users` (псевдоним `m`) действительно нет поля `UsersId`.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Contracts 
  (Id, UsersId, PhoneNumbersId, RatesId, StartDate, Balance, IsActive ) 
  SELECT 
  y.Id, m.Id, // <-- вместо m.UsersId
  p.PhoneNumbersId,r.RatesId, StartDate, Balance, IsActive
  FROM Cont y    
  LEFT JOIN Users m ON  m.Id=y.Id  
  LEFT JOIN PhoneNumbers p ON p.Id=y.Id  
  LEFT JOIN SRates r ON r.Id=y.Id";
```

Аналогично - с `c.ContractId`.

---

Это условие

```
LEFT JOIN Users m ON  m.Id=y.Id
```

выглядит подозрительно. Что оно означает (человеческими словами)?

Comment: Из таблицы Users получить идентификатор -имя,фамилия, а потом  в соответствии присоединить его к таблице Сont(Сont-таблица, в которой данные из формы)

Comment: @ValeriyaBess Это не ответ на мой вопрос :(. Вы чего хотели достичь этим JOIN-ом?

Comment: к одной таблице присоединить данные из других таблиц. Мне нужно сформировать таблицы со  ссылками на другие таблицы. Я прикрепила изображения.

Comment: `org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (UNIQUE constraint failed: Contracts.Id)`   Это после исправления

Comment: `String sql = "INSERT INTO Contracts (Id, UsersId, PhoneNumbersId, RatesId, StartDate, Balance, IsActive ) SELECT y.Id, m.Id, p.Id,r.Id, StartDate, Balance, IsActive  FROM Cont y    LEFT JOIN Users m ON  y.Id=m.Id  LEFT JOIN PhoneNumbers p ON y.Id=m.Id  LEFT JOIN SRates r ON y.Id=r.Id";`                                                                                                             `String sql = " INSERT INTO Payments ( ContractId, Amount, PaymentDate, PaymentPlace) SELECT  c.Id , Amount, PaymentDate, PaymentPlace FROM Pay x INNER JOIN  Contracts c ON x.Id=c.Id";`